# Tensorflow Extended(TFX) code runs fine on Google Colab, but throws error when running on a local machine

Tags: tensorflow, tfx

I have the following code using Tensorflow Extended(TFX)

```
from tfx.utils.dsl_utils import csv_input
from tfx.components.example_gen.csv_example_gen.component import CsvExampleGen

examples = csv_input(os.path.join(base_dir, 'data/simple'))
example_gen = CsvExampleGen(input=examples);
```

When I execute this code on Google Colab, it works fine. However, when I run this

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tfx_sample.py", line 4, in
from tfx.components.example_gen.csv_example_gen.component import CsvExampleGen
File "/Users/sv/tfx_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tfx/components/init.py", line 20, in
from tfx.components.bulk_inferrer.component import BulkInferrer
File "/Users/sv/tfx_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tfx/components/bulk_inferrer/component.py", 
line 24, in
from tfx.components.base import base_component
File "/Users/sv/tfx_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tfx/components/base/base_component.py", line 28, in
from tfx.components.base import base_driver
File "/Users/sv/tfx_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tfx/components/base/base_driver.py", line 28, in
from tfx.orchestration import metadata
File "/Users/sv/tfx_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tfx/orchestration/metadata.py", line 36, in
from ml_metadata.metadata_store import metadata_store
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ml_metadata/metadata_store/init.py", line 15, in
from ml_metadata.metadata_store.metadata_store import MetadataStore
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ml_metadata/metadata_store/metadata_store.py", line 32, in
from ml_metadata.metadata_store import pywrap_tf_metadata_store_serialized as metadata_store_serialized
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ml_metadata/metadata_store/pywrap_tf_metadata_store_serialized.py", line 28, in
_pywrap_tf_metadata_store_serialized = swig_import_helper()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ml_metadata/metadata_store/pywrap_tf_metadata_store_serialized.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tf_metadata_store_serialized', fp, pathname, description)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ml_metadata/metadata_store/_pywrap_tf_metadata_store_serialized.so, 2): Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin
Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ml_metadata/metadata_store/_pywrap_tf_metadata_store_serialized.so (which was built for Mac OS X 10.15)
Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ml_metadata/metadata_store/_pywrap_tf_metadata_store_serialized.so

Here's the version details of installed packages

apache-beam 2.20.0
tensorboard 1.15.0
tensorboard-plugin-wit 1.6.0.post3
tensorflow 1.15.0
tensorflow-data-validation 0.23.0.dev0
tensorflow-estimator 1.15.1
tensorflow-metadata 0.22.0
tensorflow-model-analysis 0.21.5
tensorflow-serving-api 2.1.0
tensorflow-transform 0.22.0
tfx 0.21.4
tfx-bsl 0.22.0

Answer (score 0):

Please use the latest version(0.29.0) available for tfx.
Working code to resolve the issue :-

```
import os
import tfx
from tfx.utils.dsl_utils import external_input
from tfx.components.example_gen.csv_example_gen.component import CsvExampleGen
import tempfile
import urllib

_data_root = tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix='tfx-data')
DATA_PATH = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tensorflow/tfx/master/tfx/examples/chicago_taxi_pipeline/data/simple/data.csv'
_data_filepath = os.path.join(_data_root, "data.csv")
urllib.request.urlretrieve(DATA_PATH, _data_filepath)

example_gen = CsvExampleGen(input_base=(_data_filepath))
```